# C: Two different binary search implementation, one stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

Here are two implementation of "forgetful" binary search, since they don't check for the exact match until they're finished.

1)

```
int bsearch1(int A[], int n, int target)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid = 0;
    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        if (target > A[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid;
    }
    if (low == high)
    {
        if (A[low] == target)
            return low;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

2)

```
int bsearch2(int A[], int n, int target)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid = 0;
    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        if (target < A[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid;
    }
    if (low == high)
    {
        if (A[low] == target)
            return low;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

NOTES: `n` is the length of array A, `target` is the element to find.

`bsearch1` works fine, but `bsearch2` runs into infinite loop, e.g A=[1,3,5,6], target=5. The diff between them is the conditional statement in while loop, the one in `bsearch2` is just the opposite of `bsearch1`. Both are perfectly right in logic. How can I know in advance `bsearch2` is "wrong"? Can any one prove that the conditional statement in `bsearch2` will lead to infinite loop (maybe in a mathematic view)? I can't find any clues and evidences until now.

EDIT:
I have evaluated the whole process of the example A=[1,3,5,6], target=5:

1.low = 0, high = 3, mid = 1, A[mid] = 3
2.low = 1, high = 3, mid = 2, A[mid] = 5
3.low = 2, high = 3, mid = 2, A[mid] = 5
...
n.low = 2, high = 3, mid = 2, A[mid] = 5

I found that `bsearch2` can not reach to `low == high` this condition, thus can not exit the while loop. But I don't know why `low` and `high` can not reach to `low == high` in the end likes `bsearch1`.

Comment: `A=[1,3,5,6]` is a pretty easy example, have you tried debugging step by step both methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your second algorithm suffers from a repeating cycle as soon as you encounter a partition where `high == (low+1)`. When that happens, you essentially have `mid = (low + low + 1)/2`, which is equivalent to `(2*low)/2 + 1/2`. With integer division, this results in `mid = low + 0`. Since your only movement on the low side is `low = mid`, but they're already equivalent, you have an infinite loop.

The reason this does *not* happen on the first implementation is the direction of the integer division loss. It is always *down*. Therefore `high` moving *down* does not suffer from this, and in-fact actually takes *advantage* of it.

To account for this in `bsearch2` the same way `bsearch1` takes advantage of the natural low-direction bias, the disgruntled rounding has to be accounted for in the mid-point calculation so it *always* moves in favor of the high-side. To do that, force the error out by biasing the calculation in the opposite direction. I.e. for `bsearch2`, do this:

```
mid = (low + high + 1) >> 1;
```

and truth be told, to avoid overflow, this really should be

```
mid = low + ((high - low + 1) >> 1);
```

This will achieve the same effect adjusting `bsearch2` midpoints that `bsearch1` does. An example is worth noting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bsearch2(int A[], int n, int target)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid = 0;
    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = low + ((high - low + 1) >> 1);
        if (target < A[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid;
    }
    if (low == high)
    {
        if (A[low] == target)
            return low;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    // build a sorted array from 1...20
    int A[20];
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A); ++i)
        A[i] = i+1;

    for (int i=0; i<=sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A)+1; ++i)
        printf("Search for %d found index %d\n", i, bsearch2(A, sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A), i));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Search for 0 found index -1
Search for 1 found index 0
Search for 2 found index 1
Search for 3 found index 2
Search for 4 found index 3
Search for 5 found index 4
Search for 6 found index 5
Search for 7 found index 6
Search for 8 found index 7
Search for 9 found index 8
Search for 10 found index 9
Search for 11 found index 10
Search for 12 found index 11
Search for 13 found index 12
Search for 14 found index 13
Search for 15 found index 14
Search for 16 found index 15
Search for 17 found index 16
Search for 18 found index 17
Search for 19 found index 18
Search for 20 found index 19
Search for 21 found index -1
```

I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the loop second time, 
low is 1, high is 3 and so mid is 2.

In the while loop, there is no 'equal' check so what is happening is that everytime target (5) is actually equal to A[mid], so you're stuck in while loop.

while entering into while add a not equal to target check

```
while (low<high && A[mid]!=target) {
…
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run the second algorithm, wait until it stuck in infinite loop. Then put a break point and see current values like `mid`, `high` and `low`.

I think that `mid` exceeds low and takes negative value. So try this code:

```
high = mid - 1 >= 0 ? mid - 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

So essentially it is caused by the property of the division of int type. In your case the "shift". They are in favor of the "Low" rather than the "high". This cannot be seen in the logic.
The conclusion is that if you don't want to use complicated if(l== r-1) , ( ==) ? : ...  thing, you always move the high rather than the low, to the mid. i.e., high = mid.  Thanks for the question.

Also, in the question of "rotated sorted array with duplicates", in the corner where mid == A[high], we want to do  --high. Actually we compare mid to A[high], not to A[L], because moving high is a better choice all the time.

https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array-ii/

```
bool search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    //the key of binary search  
    //1. l and r have to always "squeeze" the target. That is how we move r and l, and how we consider to do r = m or r = m-1 (see 378. Kth Smallest Element in a Sorted Matrix )
    //             if(count < k) { l = midv+1;}             else { r = midv;}
    //2. Try to exclude half of the data 
    int l = 0, r = nums.size()-1;
    int m, mval;

    while(l<=r) {
        m = l + ((r-l)>>1), mval = nums[m];
        if (mval == target) return true;
        if( mval < nums[r]) { //first see where the pivot is
           if(mval < target && target <= nums[r]) l = m+1;
           else r = m-1;
        } else if ( mval > nums[r] ) {
            if(nums[l] <= target && target < mval) r = m-1;
            else l = m+1;
        } else {//mval == nums[r], cannot decide pivot 
            --r; //move r while still be confident taht target is still in between
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```